# changing window background set in theme

Tags: android, background, themes

I'm implementing optimization tips for my application http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html

I have setup a splash screen (bitmap) as main window background in my root theme, that will be changed to null when the app finishes initializing:

```
<style name="Funq.Root" parent="style/Nebular.Root">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

This first part works as intended, and the Splash screen is immediately displayed when I launch the application without any delay.

However, I can't change the drawable to null later on, by code.

```
  getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

is ignored. The drawable set on the Theme prevails.

Any idea?

Thanks!